# favicon.ico doesn't appear when I deploy application to google app engine

Tags: html, google-app-engine, favicon

I have placed favicon.ico in the web-pages  directory of my project. I also placed a tag in the jsp page to put the favicon on the browser :

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="./favicon.ico"/>
```

but still the favicon doesn't appear in the browser.

Why is that ? What do I need to do put the favicon in the browser.

Comment: are you pushing your favicon to appengine as a static resource ?

Comment: @Tim Hoffman no.what is that?

Comment: images, css, js all need to be deployed via static resources in app.yaml.  See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/appconfig_yaml#Static_Files_and_Resource_Files for more details.  You may not be using app.yaml but there are xml equivalents - https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Static_Files_and_Resource_Files

Answer (score 2):

Even if the favicon path gets resolved correctly, you might still need to clear the browser's favicon cache (happened to me once).

For example with Safari/Mac OS: Quit the browser, then delete the file $HOME/Library/Safari/WebpageIcons.db.

Comment: A hard refresh `SHIFT+F5` solved the issue for me. The new favicon started to show.

Answer (score 1):

URLs need to be resolved as a real public web address not server side paths.

Try this:

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/favicon.ico"  rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

or

```
<link href="<c:url value="/favicon.ico"/>" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```