# Add favicon to Google apps script from inside a domain

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm having trouble getting my icon to show up for any google apps script inside my domain.

[Google docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#setfaviconurliconurl) say to write it like this:

```
var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>Hello, world!</b>');
output.setFaviconUrl('http://www.example.com/image.png');
```

But there is no guidance on how to use a url for a file in a public folder inside my domain.
My urls look like:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/[googleId]/view?usp=drive_link
```

And then I get an error message saying my file is the wrong type. If I append &type=.png to my url, the type message goes away, and I see the Google Apps Script icon (white arrow on blue square)

When I inspect the browser, I think I'm seeing the root problem:

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://drive.google.com/file/d/[Google ID]/view?usp=drive_link&type=.png with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

I did also go down the rabbit hole of trying to specify raw .svg codes and that was totally ignored.

I'm looking for a solid solution in 2023. I see one answer that would be embedding my app into a blank google site. That would work, but I'd like to make it work the way it is designed.

I'm not against some free / cheap hosting for the urls but I do not want to use anyone's ip without permission.
I see some other questions, but no solutions that work for this specific problem (self host favicon inside google domain)

[favicon for web app doesnt load by apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68908070/favicon-for-web-app-doesnt-load-by-apps-script)

[favicon.ico doesn't appear when I deploy application to google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698610/favicon-ico-doesnt-appear-when-i-deploy-application-to-google-app-engine?rq=4)

Comment: How about [Is there a way to host a favicon on Google Drive for a Google Web App?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67393002/1330560)

Answer (score 2):

ok the answer was on this one [Is there a way to host a favicon on Google Drive for a Google Web App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51713596/is-there-a-way-to-host-a-favicon-on-google-drive-for-a-google-web-app/67393002#67393002)

```
    function doGet() {
      const IMAGEID = "--Google ID--"
      const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("Index")
      return html.addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
        .setFaviconUrl(`https://drive.google.com/uc?id=${IMAGEID}&export=download&format=png`)
        .setTitle("My app with an icon!")
    }
```